# Laravel Function that hold two parameters

Tags: php, laravel

**My Controller**

```
public function showSpecificSite($site_id){

$reports = Report::whereHas('site', function($query) use($site_id) {
    $query->where('site_id', $site_id);
})->get(['email_date', 'url', 'recipient']);

$siteName = Site::find($site_id)->site_name;

  return view('newsite', compact('site_id', 'siteName', 'reports'));
}

public function showMonthlyReport($site_id, $report_id)
{

$site = Report::whereHas('site', function($query) use($site_id) {
    $query->where('site_id', $site_id);
})->get();

$report = $site->Report::find($report_id);

return view('reports')->with('report', $report)->with('site_id',$site_id)
->with('report_id', $report_id);
}
```

**My Route**

```
Route::get('sites/{site_id}',['as'=>'SpecificSite','uses'=>'ReportController@showSpecificSite']);

Route::get('sites/{site_id}/report/{report_id}', ['as'=>'Reports', 'uses' => 'ReportController@showMonthlyReport']);
```

**My blade view**

```
<a href="{{route('SpecificSite',['site_id'=>$record->site_id])}}">view</a>  

<a href="{{route('Reports',['site_id'=>$report->site_id, 'report_id'=>$report->report_id])}}">view</a>
```

**Site Model**

```
public function report()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Report');
}
```

**Report Model**

```
public function site()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Site');
}
```

**My print_r($report)**

```
App\Report Object
(
[fillable:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => site_url
        [1] => reciepients
        [2] => monthly_email_date
    )

[connection:protected] => 
[table:protected] => 
[primaryKey:protected] => id
[keyType:protected] => int
[perPage:protected] => 15
[incrementing] => 1
[timestamps] => 1
[attributes:protected] => Array
    (
        [email_date] => 2018-08-23
        [url] => http://foyston.com
        [recipient] => cgallarmin@gmail.com
    )

[original:protected] => Array
    (
        [email_date] => 2018-08-23
        [url] => http://foyston.com
        [recipient] => cgallarmin@gmail.com
    )

[relations:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[hidden:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[visible:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[appends:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[guarded:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => *
    )

[dates:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[dateFormat:protected] => 
[casts:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[touches:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[observables:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[with:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[morphClass:protected] => 
[exists] => 1
[wasRecentlyCreated] => )1
```

My showSpecificSite function was working so well. My localhost is look like this `http://localhost:8000/sites/1/` `==` `http://localhost:8000/sites/$site_id/`

Now my problem is my showMonthlyReport.
`http://localhost:8000/sites/report` `==` `http://localhost:8000/sites/null/report/null`
This is the path that I always get.

It should be `http://localhost:8000/sites/1/report/1`

Any idea to fix this issue?
Sorry for my bad grammar I'm not that well in English.

Thank you in Advance!~

Comment: It seems to me that your `uses` is wrong, can you check that?

Comment: It's like this `['as'=>'Reports', 'uses => ReportController@showMonthlyReport']`. `uses => xx` being a whole string instead of key-pair

Comment: @Phiter just fixed already but still same error. My site_id and report_id were still null.

Comment: what happens if you php artisan route:list ? by what happens, i mean... how is this route printed on this command?

Comment: Can you try moving the `Reports` route above the `SpecificSite` route?

Comment: `GET|HEAD | sites/{site_id} | SpecificSite | App\Http\Controllers\ReportController@showSpecificSite`

`GET|HEAD | sites/{site_id}/report/{report_id} | Reports | App\Http\Controllers\ReportController@showMonthlyReport`

Comment: @Phiter NotFoundHttpException same problem it gives me this path `http://localhost:8000/sites//report`

Comment: sorry to ask, but does report has a report_id? is this valid: $report->report_id? shouldn it be $report->id? Also, what happens when you dd($report) on the controller, or when you print_r($report) on the view

Comment: @Erubiel on my database it was `report_id` was that bad to put like this ` $report->report_id`?

Comment: Sorry, its a laravel "standard" to use the col 'id'  for the primary key of the table... Not "tablename_id"... since that is the standard i thought that might be causing the problem, but if thats what you've got defined on DB, should be working.

Comment: @Erubiel where should I dd($report) is it monthlyreport function?

Comment: I dont see anywhere this report_id, site_id variables, Also, off topic but avoid using valid email addresses on code you post here, or while testing. use something like some@example.org address.

Comment: I've tried to put it on my reports but it says not NotFoundHttpException cause my path is always like this `http://localhost:8000/sites//report`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem by this.

```
public function showSpecificSite($site_id){

$reports = Report::whereHas('site', function($query) use($site_id) {
    $query->where('site_id', $site_id);
})->get(['email_date', 'url', 'recipient', 'report_id', 'site_id']);

$siteName = Site::find($site_id)->site_name;

return view('newsite', compact('site_id', 'siteName', 'reports'));
}
```

Its because I'm only getting three data from my site that's why my ID's are null.
But thank you so much guys for helping me. Have a great day!~

Answer (score 0):

In your controller change the way you pass the data to the view

```php
view('reports', ['report' => $report, 'site_id' => $site_id, 'report_id' => $report_id]);
```

Since `$report` does not have a `site_id` or a `report_id`, but you calculate them and pass em in your controller as `$site_id` and `$report_id`, you should change this

```php
<a href="{{route('Reports',['site_id'=>$report->site_id, 'report_id'=>$report->report_id])}}">view</a>
```

to this

```php
<a href="{{route('Reports',['site_id'=>$site_id, 'report_id'=>$report_id])}}">view</a>
```

Comment: It gives me error on that blade view. Undefined variable: report_id

Comment: Undefined variable: report but I declare it on my function.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you must generate your routes:

```
<a href="{{ route('SpecificSite', [$record->site]) }}">view</a>
<a href="{{ route('Reports', [$report->site, $report]) }}">view</a>
```

The way you are doing, each array key will become a parameter in the query string.

Comment: The thing is my SpecificSite was already declared to my home view that's why I need to get that data already but it seems so hard to find out how to do that

Answer (score -1):

You cant use anchor and link to route that has two parameters you can 
1-make a route and send data to that route with form.
2-redirect to your route with this have been gotten data.
code:

```
public function redirectroute(Request $request){
        return Redirect::to('sites/'.$request->site_id.'/report'.$request->report_id)->with(compact('request'));
    }
```

and then do your jobs.

Comment: @Christian could my answer help you?

Comment: Let me try. Hopefully it would help. @AbolfazlMohajeri

Comment: @Christian yes try this

Comment: same all my ids are still null bro but thank for trying to help me.