# Laravel version upgrade affects your controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

**My ReportController**

```
use App\Site;
use App\Report;


public function showSpecificSite($site_id){

$reports = Report::whereHas('site', function($query) use($site_id) {
    $query->where('site_id', $site_id);
})->get(['email_date', 'url', 'recipient', 'report_id', 'site_id']);

$siteName = Site::find($site_id)->site_name;

return view('newsite', compact('site_id', 'siteName', 'reports'));
}

Route::get('sites/{site_id}',['as'=>'SpecificSite','uses'=>'ReportController@showSpecificSite']);
```

**Site Model**

```
public function report()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Report');
}
```

**Report Model**

```
public function site()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Site');
}
```

**My blade view**

```
<a href="{{route('SpecificSite',['site_id'=>$record->site_id])}}">view</a>
```

Here is the problem I upgrade my laravel version 5.2.36 to 5.4.36
This is working well in the 5.2 version here is the article that is running.
[Laravel Function that hold two parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51973771/laravel-function-that-hold-two-parameters)

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'reports.site_site_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `email_date`, `url`, `recipient`, `report_id`, `site_id` from `reports` where exists (select * from `sites` where `reports`.`site_site_id` = `sites`.`site_id` and `site_id` = 1))

My route:list is the same before. I also have my routes/web.app folder already.
Is it possible that your controller function got affected when you upgrade your laravel version? Any idea how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like something changed at how Laravel "guesses" the FK name in a relation (so rather the Model class than your Controller). You can always specify the FK name explicitely in the optional params to `belongsTo`.

Comment: how can I do that? @TobiasK

Comment: The signature is `public function belongsTo($related, $foreignKey = null, $ownerKey = null, $relation = null)`. Given your FK in the Reports-table is named `site_id` you would do: `return $this->belongsTo('App\Site', 'site_id');`

Comment: @TobiasK can you put that to answer so I can check it!~ Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error involves a column that is used in one of your relations, it is more likely something changed at how Laravel "guesses" the FK column-name in a relation (Model class), rather than something in your Controller.

You can specify the FK name explicitely in the optional params to `belongsTo`, then it will not guess it. Check the signature:

```php
public function belongsTo($related, $foreignKey = null, $ownerKey = null, $relation = null)
```

Given your FK in the Reports-table is named `site_id` you would do:

```php
public function site()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Site', 'site_id');
}
```

---

I digged a bit into it and found the breaking change (introduced in 5.4): https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/16847 .

This has however been documented in [the 5.4 Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade):

> If the foreign key is not explicitly specified when defining a relationship, Eloquent will now use the table name and primary key name for the related model to build the foreign key. (...)  [T]he behavior could be different from previous releases if you are overriding the `$primaryKey` property or `getKeyName` method of the [related] model.